# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode instantiation returns timeout expired

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I've been working around with Fabric for a a few months now, and I've been trying to run a somewhat complex virtual machine, the Ethereum Virtual Machine within a chaincode. It is written in JavaScript so I worked with the nodeJS chaincode version.
I packed the the VM with my chaincode in a directory that i install and instantiate onto the peer. The install completes and exits with no errors, however the instantiation after hanging for a few minutes returns me an error:

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout expired while starting chaincode mychaincode:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:....
```

It should run for quite a few minutes at least as the added packages are ~15MB, according to the example nodejs chaincode runs for a minute at least.

The example nodejs chaincode (chaincode_example02) runs perfectly on both BYFN network from the tutorial and on a basic-network that I've started. My environment was set up according to the documentation (v1.1.0) from the fabric-samples repository (v1.1.0). Even if I only add one package to the example chaincode with the require method, it hangs, than return error.

I've been searching for a flag or config where I can set the timeout value for chaincode instantiation, but with no luck. Where could I increase the timeout value? 
Which log should I provide in order to step forward in searching for the soution?

Thanks is advance,
Balint

Comment: Interesting... as an aside note that we are working on formal support (potentially) for EVM in fabric https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6590 - that said, we'd need to look at the logs from the chaincode container.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAqAh.png - here i provide a screenshot of my peer's log, 'peer0.org1.example.com' , I can't provide any specific logs from the chaincode container itself, because it is not created at all beacause of the timeout. 
(the first error resulted in me installing the chaincode again by mistake)

Comment: Are you sure it is not created-and then deleted after the timeout? 
You can do "docker ps -a" and see if any container exited.

Comment: FWIW, you can modify the chaincode.startuptimeout config by adding a CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT environment variable to the base/peer-base.yaml docker compose file specifying something other than the default.

Comment: the "docker ps -a" command show no containers exited other than my previously terminated ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the chaincode.startuptimeout config by adding a `CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT` environment variable to the base/peer-base.yaml docker compose file specifying something other than the default.

Comment: I've tried to set several ("big number") values for the CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT variable in the peer-base.yaml, but I still get the timeout error. I assume that the provided value for it is in 'seconds'. Is there a maximum value, or an option to set it undefined, therefore it leaves the code run forever?

Comment: The default is 300s or 5 minutes. Are you experiencing that the failure is still occurring after a period consistent with the timeout value you set? maybe if you could share the peer logs via pastebin or gist there might be additional insights we could provide.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QjAxVgy5 - full log of my peer that is targeted during instantiation. I've set the timeout=600000.

Comment: With 6000 and 600000, both time exited around 2 minutes after start.

Comment: something about how you are setting the timeout seems off. The logs show that the timeout is configured as 0s and it is defaulting to 5s, and indeed that is when it is timing out building the chaincode image. I double checked to be sure that the ENV variable will affect the timeout and it works correctly. Where are you setting the env var? in the base/peer-base.yaml? Can you share that please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KMW8ZCH8 - this is what my ../first-network/base/peer-base.yaml looks like. I'm starting the network with the docker-compose-cli.yaml, but if I'm right it extends the peer-base.yaml indirectly so that shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: try a value of 300s or 5 minutes. It takes about 15-20 seconds to build the image which is where you were timing out.

Comment: with the 's' given at the and of the timeout value, the timeout works like a charm :) It enabled me to get the created chaincode container's name to see it's logs. I had a problem with the way of importing the packages. My code stops at the first wrong import and hangs there, that is why i still get timeout error, Thank you for your help, it really helped me a lot!