# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode instantiation returns timeout expired: package.json not found

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

**Edit**: i solved it! it was a problem with my deploy script and pwd. Aparently the **peer install** doesn't prompt any error if there are no source files as long as the route exists.

I'm trying to deploy a chaincode developed on NodeJS over the Fabric v1.1.0-preview docker images but I'm getting a `[chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 039 launchAndWaitForRegister failed: timeout expired while starting chaincode`.

For now is as chaincode_example02 but with the **init** function modified to match my own (chaincode_example02 runs OK btw).

I'm using `basic-network` under `fabric-samples`

The error seems similar to [Hyperledger Fabric chaincode instantiation returns timeout expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662877/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-instantiation-returns-timeout-expired), but in this case my container for the chaincode it's been created.

When I look the logs it prompts:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/src/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-11T09_00_28_708Z-debug.log
```

Any clue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Comment: How did you solve it? Having the same issue.

Comment: @noodles_ftw read first line, the **edit**

Comment: @DavidSanchez-Seco yeah, turned out I was installing the chaincode from the root of the chaincode's folder, instead of from the node folder withing the chaincode's folder. Thanks!